# How i toggle a div with 2 different images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys my problem is i used 2 different images for toggling a div. `Image 2.gif` is down arrow and `image 1.png` up arrow. Actually this script is the one I used for my responsive dropdown menu. So please anybody help me, where i am doing wrong.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){
        if ($(this).img()=="<img src="2.gif" alt="" />")
            $(this).img("<img src="1.gif" alt="" />")
            else
                $(this).img("<img src="2.gif" alt="" />")
                $("div").toggle(300);
     });
  });
</script>
```

**Css**

```
div{ border:1px solid #000; margin:10px 10px 0 0; width:300px;    padding:10px; float:left; clear:both;}
span{float:left; width:100%;}
```

**HTML**

```
<span><img src="2.gif" alt="" class="open" /></span>
<div style="display:none;">test box</div>
```

please help my how top toggle my div currently this script not working.

Comment: not `$(this).img()=...`. it is `$(this).attr("src") =="2.gif"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.img()` is not a valid jQuery function, unless you are using any plugins. 
What needs to be done is use [**`attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to get/set `src` attribute for an image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('src') == "http://dummyimage.com/100x60/000/fff"){
            $(this).attr('src','http://dummyimage.com/100x60/666/000');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src','http://dummyimage.com/100x60/000/fff');
        }
        $("div").toggle(300);
    });
});
```

```css
div{ border:1px solid #000; margin:10px 10px 0 0; width:300px;    padding:10px; float:left; clear:both;}
span{float:left; width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x60/666/fff" alt="" class="open" /></span>
<div style="display:none;">test box</div>
```

Comment: Oh! you right Mr. Krishnan but this script also one time toggle and i am using 2 diffident images for this div 1 image for open div and 2nd for close

Comment: Mr.  Rejith R Krishnan may i ask you a another different question?

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla yes.